# SharePoint 2013 on-premises migration to AWS with Workflow Manager

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, aws

We have requirement to move the existing on-premise SP 2013 farm to AWS .

We planned to build the SP farm in AWS instances and SQL to AWS SQL RDS

We are using Workflow Manager 1.0 and Service bus configuration to execute SP custom workflows.

Will AWS Windows Server instances support this Workflow Manager configuration?

Is network speed support between SP Application servers and SQL RDS on azure?

Will there be any specific challenges to address during this migration?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is network speed support between SP Application servers and SQL RDS on azure?

Minimum requirements are:
Windows Auth; the SQL Server must be joined to Active Directory

1Gbps connectivity between SharePoint and SQL

1ms one-way response time between SharePoint and SQL

In addition, you cannot use Office Online Server/Office Web Apps in a hosted scenario where the VM may move (if you have a dedicated physical server(s), that is allowed). This is due to OOS/OWA lack of license mobility.

There's nothing that would preclude hosting WFM in an IaaS scenario, but again it needs to be joined to your AD.